# Question rapidly deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

Why was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738930/kruskal-algorithmunionfindset deleted?  It was asking how a well-known data structure (variously called "disjoint set forests" and "union-find") works and doesn't appear to me to fit any of the closing criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the post was self-deleted by the author.

At the time of deletion, the post had a score of -2 and had attracted 2 close votes, so the author must've thought to cut their losses.

The question *may* have been better suited to [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), had the author added some more background on the algorithm (link to Wikipedia perhaps).

Comment: OK, cool.  Bugs me because I was 80% of the way through an answer.

Comment: @tmyklebu, that can be frustrating indeed. You can always try to convince people to undelete and re-open. This being said, the question would need to be improved (you can edit it too), at the very least to replace "*I already know how the Algorithm works*" by some pseudo code describing how it works and where the "*UnionFindSet*" is, otherwise, it's not really a good question unfortunately...

Comment: another topic. But I myself have been targeted by user using that +1 and -1 and he stated that openly and only then I knew this, so no assumptions.. here.

Comment: @Amit: And yet they could be lying about it. Why the obsession over it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters fact is I **really** downvoted a answer and a user noticed that and he downvoted my answer.. and I had no explanation for him to trick him to believing I hadn't downvoted his answer as I don't get 2+ for edits as my reps was > 2000 and hadn't accepted any other answer for my question and I couldn't help but accept it.. Thought this shouldn't happen to others.. other than that, I've nothing with this to be obsessed..

Comment: @AmitJoki: So that user made an assumption, that happened to be correct. Now you are assuming they had some kind of special power, they don't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's what they do and we'll tend to do.. You might not do that, because -2 won't even capture your eyes, but they do as we've 4-5 digit reps and you have humongous 6 digit one. :)

Comment: @Bruno: I don't really think this is worth pursuing further.  (It wasn't worded very well, but I felt I could give an answer that was useful and responsive to anyone who wondered the same thing.)

Comment: @AmitJoki: You can never stop people from assuming.

Comment: @MartijnPieters fact..

Comment: @tmyklebu, you've obviously pursued it enough to raise a question on Meta, having written most of an answer, so it might have been worth giving it a go, by adding a bit more context to the question. This being said, Programmers.SE would probably have been a better place anyway.

Comment: @Bruno: Yes, then Martijn answered the meta question to my satisfaction.  I had to wait 15 minutes to accept his answer.